# Web Application Toolkit for Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to install "Web Application Toolkit for Bing Maps". What are the prerequisits for this? I have Visual Web Developer for 2008; but Silverlight template is not there.

Could you please list out the required environment with Visual Web Developer for 2008 for working in "Web Application Toolkit for Bing Maps" ?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the Silverlight Tools installing. See: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/